# Timing effects in slides made with LaTeX

Tags: image, latex, slide, timing, beamer

I'm trying to create a presentation with class Beamer in LaTeX. I learnt how to use command like \pause, \only and \onslide but I don't understand how to program with a specific time the effects I've inserted in the slide.
For example, I've the following piece of code

```
\includegraphics<1>[scale=0.3]{photo1.eps}
\includegraphics<2>[scale=0.3]{photo2.eps}
```

What I want is... "Dear LaTeX, show me first photo1.eps and after 5 seconds, for example, photo2.eps, on the same slide, of course", automatically, without my action.
Is it possibile to do that??? Can anyone help me??? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the `\transduration` command, as explained on page 142 in the [beamer manual](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf):

> You can also specify how long a given slide should be shown, using the
>   following overlay-specification-aware command: \transduration<⟨overlay
>   specification⟩>{⟨number of seconds⟩} In full screen mode, show the
>   slide for ⟨number of seconds⟩. If zero is specified, the slide is
>   shown as short as possible. This can be used to create interesting
>   pseudo-animations. Example: \transduration<2>{1}